# Clear ComboBox Containig an Array VBA and Repopulate with Column Index

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, dynamic-arrays, listobject

I have a sigle column ComboBox that I have populated with a dynamic array; however, I'd like the code to replace the value of the combo box with respective column from my ListBox.

```
'Prepares the Active Escorts list box.
ivb = 0
i = 0
With frmEntry
      
    .listboxActiveEscorts.Clear
    .listboxActiveEscorts.ColumnHeads = False
    .listboxActiveEscorts.ColumnCount = "15"
    .listboxActiveEscorts.ColumnWidths = "0,100,100,0,0,100,100,0,0,0,0,0,100,100,80"
    
    i = 0
        
    'Badge # combobox properties
    ReDim vbArray(0 To vbArrayCount - 1)
    For i = 0 To vbArrayCount - 1
        ivb = ivb + 1
        vbArray(ivb - 1) = loVisBadge.Range.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value
    Next i
    .cbxVisitorBadgeNumber.List = vbArray
    
End With
```

This population of the ComboBox executes beautifully, in my belief, but if you see a better way to implement the dynamic list, I'm all ears.

I have a button that I will use to reset the form, which also works for the most part. When an item is selected from the list, I am able to clear all controls except for the ComboxBox containing the array of values. I will be adding two additional arrays to each of the other ComboBoxes on the form, and I imagine I am going to have the same problem: "Could not set the value property. Invalid property value"

This is the code assigned to click event of the ListBox:

```
Private Sub listboxActiveEscorts_Click()

With frmEntry
    
   .cbxEscortSelectName.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(1) + " " + .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(2)
   .txtCredential.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(4)
   .txtEscortCompany.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(3)
   .cbxVisitorName.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(5) + " " + .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(6)
   .txtVECompany.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(7)
   .txtVEDOB.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(8)
   .txtVEIdentification.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(9)
   .txtVEIDNumber.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(10)
   .txtVEExpirationDate.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(11)
   .txtVEStart.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(12)
   .txtVEEnd.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(13)
   '.cbxVisitorBadgeNumber.Value = ""
   .cbxVisitorBadgeNumber = vbNullString
   .cbxVisitorBadgeNumber.Value = .listboxActiveEscorts.Column(14)

End With

End Sub
```

What am I missing here. I tried to ReDim the array that assigned the values, but that didn't work. Is it a data type thing, perhaps?

[image]

In the picture below, you'll see the values populated in the controls, all except the visitor badge # (ComboBox which throws the error...I have commented out the line for illustration purposes, so you'll see the visitor badge # is blank).

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Column Index"? Why your code increments `ivb` at each iteration and then use it as `ivb -1`? In which way `loVisBadge.Range.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value` returns a "Column Index"?

Comment: I would suggest `vbArray = loVisBadge.Range("A2:A" & vbArrayCount +1).Value`. Supposing that `vbArrayCount` means the number of list items. No `ReDim`, no iteration... Than, use `.cbxVisitorBadgeNumber.List = vbArray`. Of course, if those "Column Indexes" have to be extracted from the range in discussion...

Comment: By 'Column Index', I mean the row position within the column, if that makes sense. It's really the 'Column' property, basically. @FaneDuru I will give that a shot.

Comment: If so, your iteration extract it from some cells value.  I thought that you want iterating by rows and extract it from the iterated cells value. Which looked strange, that's why I insisted to clarify the issue. Now, can you explain what `loVisBadge` is, in fact? Is it a range on a row? If so, the suggestion should be changed. If not, what is it, in fact? But, I will leave my office in some minutes... If clarify the issue until I leave, I will try making a new suggestion. If not and nobody else suggests something useful, I will look at it in some hours, when I will be at home.

Comment: The ```ivb - 1``` is used match the first position in the array, since the counter has to iterate succinctly with the starting point of the array through the entire loop. So it will always be ```ivb = ivb + 1``` which sets the counter to 1 and increments over the loop, but I need zero, ```vbArray(ivb - 1) for the index since I did not use Option Base 1.

Comment: loVisBadge is the list object. The ListObject rows are used to assing the values to positions in the array. Maybe my method is strange...basically, I loop through the cells to add values to the dynamic array. This array can grow or shrink based on the number of items in the range. This file/sheet will be reproduced dozens of times, each a different number of visitor badges. I needed the array to scale with the values in the column.

Comment: I think it is useless... Let us take first iteration: `ivb = ivb + 1` returns 1. Then why using `vbArray(ivb - 1)`. You can simple use `i` or directly `ivb`, which is zero if you do not increment it in the previous code line. But, forget about that. Do you have an answer at my previous comment? Please post here the address of `loVisBadge` and try explaining what you want to extract from it. If columns between a starting column to an ending one, `Evaluate` could return it without any iteration...

Comment: " the values in the column" or the columns themselves? I must leave my office  now...

Comment: Values in the column.

Comment: I am driving now...

Comment: If  `loVisBadge is the list object, as you say, your code returns all values of the first column. Not columns values of a list object row. What do you need, in fact, from this point of view? Do you want to return the columns headers, as "Columns Index"?

Comment: I would like the Visitor Badge ComboBox to display the Visitor Badge # from the corresponding row of the ListBox when that row is selected. For example, if row with name Walter Mannig is selector, Visitor Badge ComboBox (cbxVisitorBadgeNumber) should display "2".

Comment: I do not understand anything... Are you talking about the first code or about the second one? If about the second one, this only means that the number you need is not in column  14, as your code tries returning it. It depends on how you loaded the list box.

Comment: @FaneDuru I first said that the combobox is loaded with values stored in an array (vbArray). Then I said that I want the array to be removed from the combobox and replaced with a value from column 14 from the listbox based on which row is selected. Not sure how to make it more clearer than that.

Comment: If not something confidential, can you share the workbook?